# Display data from Twig without reload the page

Tags: php, jquery, html, twig, octobercms

First of all i want to ask about how can i make my code to be able for the user when clicked the a href then it will display `{{media.content}}` by hiding other result of looping. 
Right now, user of cms need to create a new pages just to call the component for viewing specific pages and it involved some coding that they dont know.

```
{% set medias = __SELF__.medias %}
<div class="post-list">
    {% for media in medias %}
    <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "/about/media-room/media-coverage", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>

    <div class="post-item">
        <h3 class="oc-text-title"><a id="demo" class="link_orange" onclick="loadDoc()">{{ media.title }}</a></h3>
        <p class="oc-text-paragraph">{{ media.published_at|date('j F Y') }}</p>

        {% if media.introductory %}
        <!--<p class="introductory">{{ media.introductory|raw }}</p>-->
        {% else %}
        <!--<div class="content">{{ media.content|raw }}</div>-->
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <span class="no-data">{{ noMediasMessage }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{{ medias.render|raw }}
```

So how can i make this happen without need to create a new pages by clicking an a href then it will goes to its respected content?

See pictures below

---

*Here is the all looping result*

[image: Looping]

---

*And i want to make the a href view the content like this without need to load pages. just hide the looping and view its content*

[image: Content view]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want the a-link to open a new page? Then try this: `<a href="javascript:;" id="demo" class="link_orange" onclick="loadDoc()">{{ media.title }}</a>` (notice the: `href="javascript:;"`). If that isn't what you're asking, then I have no idea what you mean =/

Comment: u may take a look at the picture i attach above. basically it will load a new pages with loading of its content. but the problem is i want to avoid for the user to create a new pages. so the a href will dynamically call its {{ media.content }}

Comment: you could bring all the information and hide the elements that will be shown when clicking the link, or load them using an ajax call... also you need your links to avoid the predefined behaviour and don't call a document... I don't use `<a>` tags, I simulate them using CSS on a `<p>` tag for example...

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could solve this. Instead of fetching the content by `ajax`, place it already inside the `html` and use some javascript to `toggle` it's container.

```js
 $(function() {
  $('.post-item h3 a.link_orange').on('click', function(e) {
   $(this).parent().next().next().slideToggle();
  });
 });
```

```css
 .hidden {
  display : none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post-list">
    {% for media in medias %}
  <div class="post-item">
   <h3 class="oc-text-title">
    <a class="link_orange">{{ media.title }}</a>
   </h3>
   <p class="oc-text-paragraph">{{ media.published_at|date('j F Y') }}</p>

   {% if media.introductory %}
    <p class="hidden introductory">{{ media.introductory|raw }}</p
   {% else %}
    <div class="hidden content">{{ media.content|raw }}</div>
   {% endif %}
  </div>
    {% else %}
  <span class="no-data">{{ noMediasMessage }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: seems like not working. but if i use $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(); it will only toggle the <p class="oc-text-paragraph">{{ media.published_at|date('j F Y') }}</p> any idea?